# SSIS - execute N concurrent instances of the same task

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, parameters, ssis, parallel-processing

There is an SSIS package I am currently working on. What it does is that it runs the very same SQL statement 10 times, each time with a different value of a parameter N (N goes from 0 to 9). Statements are independent of each other (they are simply INSERT INTO ... SELECT * FROM ... WHERE some_int_column % 10 = N).

My current implementation is very naïve: I created 10 copies of the same .sql file with 10 different values of N, then created 10 separate "Execute SQL" tasks and pointed each task to a different SQL file.

This works fine. But now I need to be able to dynamically change the maximum value of N i.e. to create Nmax parallel tasks, each with a different parameter value (from 0 to Nmax-1).

How should I approach this? I was thinking of a FOR loop but you can't get an asynchronous FOR loop in SSIS so this isn't going to work. Any other ideas?

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Doesn't have to be in SSIS, also doesn't have to be done with loops. You should be able to modify your procedure so that it uses `@n` in a set-based manner.

Comment: Yeah... but, I don't want to. I am loading data from a linked server that limits throughput for a single session so I need multiple concurent load tasks so overcome this limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do this with a Script Component.

It would contain a loop from 1 to N
and call

```
SqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery
```

which is asynchronous (ie, it returns immediately).

This would give the parallelism that you require.

Comment: Nice suggestion (+1!), just remember to use in conjunction with `EndExecuteNonQuery`. Also, I think that you can only execute `BeginExecuteNonQuery` once per command object, until you call the end of execution, so to achieve parallelism you'll have to spawn N command objects too.

Comment: `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` might be better?

Comment: Sounds smart. I will give it a try and revert soon. Until then I am marking your answer as the best one. Thanks!

Comment: @gvee makes a valid point. ExecuteNonQueryAsync might be better (and simpler).

Comment: I have been testing this approach for the last couple of hours and it seem to be working just fine. Problem solved - thanks Mike!

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, we do everything we can to avoid looping.

We think in sets.

Assuming your existing procedure looks something like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE some_procedure (
   @n int
)
  AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT INTO something (column_list)
  SELECT column_list
  FROM   something_else
  WHERE  some_int_column % 10 = @n
  ;
END
;
```

Here's a very tiny change, see if you can spot it!

```
ALTER PROCEDURE some_procedure (
   @n int
)
  AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT INTO something (column_list)
  SELECT column_list
  FROM   something_else
  WHERE  some_int_column % 10 <= @n
  ;
END
;
```

Did you see it? `= @n` became `<= @n`

Consider that you want to do this for `@n=0` to `@n=3`. In the first procedure we would do:

```
EXEC some_procedure @n=0;
EXEC some_procedure @n=1;
EXEC some_procedure @n=2;
EXEC some_procedure @n=3;
```

But with the update, we can just do:

```
EXEC some_procedure @n=3;
```

---

**Update regarding parallelism:**

Unfortunately SSIS doesn't currently contain this kind of functionality in a ForEach loop. This has been raised as a Connect item in the past (https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/544304/ssis-parallel-foreach-loop) but it doesn't look like it will be appearing any time soon.

As far as I can see you have two other options:

1. Create `X` ForEach loop tasks in SSIS and have them handle the `@n%X` tasks between them. Obviously this means you only get as much parallelism as the number of tasks you create.
2. Roll your own managed code solution that can spawn its own threads.

Not the answer you were looking for, but you these are the all alternatives I can think of at this stage!

---

Sorry, I know this isn't the best explanation, so please ask anything you want in the comments if something isn't clear and I'll try and improve my answer!

Comment: Thanks for educating me on SQL! Believe me or not, I do think in sets. I have been working with SQL databases for years and years now and I know all the caveats of loops, cursors and so on. But for this particular task, parallelizing the load makes things go faster (from 140 minutes down to 20 minutes) for reasons that are beyond this discussion.

Comment: @xpil unfortunately looping in SSIS isn't going to give you parallelism, because the tasks will effectively be queued! You may get a performance gain from the results being dealt with in smaller batches, though? One workaround may be to create X tasks (where X=number of available parallel threads) and then make each one do `@n%X` tasks?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am trying to achieve except that I want X to be a variable, not a constant.

Comment: @xpil unfortunately I'm a bit stumped as to how to achieve that within SSIS. You might be able to do it with some managed code that spawns its own threads, but SSIS isn't that dynamic in and of itself. Parallel ForLoop containers have been raised with MS before (https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/544304/ssis-parallel-foreach-loop) but doesn't look like it's coming any time soon.

Comment: OK gvee, thanks a lot - I am going to take this as the best answer possible for now. Have a nice day!

Comment: @xpil best of luck with it, let us know if you come up with a more elegant solution than just adding X tasks!